# C# appSettings in dot notation

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik, web-config

I have a lot of `<appSettings>` in an asp.net 4.5 WebForms application

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="SomeStringKeyName" value="SomeStringValue">
    ..
</appSettings>
```

I also have a static class for accessing these settings:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;

public static class AppSetting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of this setting
    /// </summary>
    static public string SomeStringKeyName { get; set; }

    // ... many static string variables

    static AppSetting()
    {
        // Cache all these values in static properties.
        SomeStringKeyName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeStringKeyName"];
        //... plus many more
    }
}
```

I use some 3rd party controls such as Telerik ASP.NET Ajax. It's possible to configure default attributes for these in the App Settings. They use dot notation to namespace the settings. I find this makes it a lot easier to organise the settings.

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="Telerik.Web.UI.RenderMode" value="lightweight" />
</appSettings>
```

There are also some asp configuration settings that use colon notation:

```xml
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="WebForms" />
```

I would like to use either of the above patterns for my `<appSettings>`and `AppSetting` class. Is there any built in functionality in asp.net or `Telerik.Web.UI` that I can use or do I need to write string parsing methods myself?

I want to store my XML appSettings like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

<add key="MyApp.MyComponent.Setting" value="SomeValue" />
```

And access them like this in C#:

```
AppSetting.MyApp.MyComponent.Setting
```

Comment: I believe this is just disambiguating the key name - in case of multiple values with the same name - and no special processing is required - i.e. `SomeStringKeyName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Company.App.Namespace.SomeStringKeyName"];`

Comment: But I want to access it elsewhere like `AppSetting.Company.App.Namespace.SomeStringKeyName`

Comment: Not sure you can do that easily (or at all), but you could do `Company.App.Namespace.AppSetting.SomeStringKeyName` with the class you have already